# Can I use CAT6e on a CAT6 Patch panel?

Tags: cable, patch-panel

I have a customer that is set on using CAT6e cables throughout his building. My job is to terminate the ends into patch panels.

Can't really find any info if CAT6e will get the full 10GBPS at 100 meters if used in a CAT6 patch panel. I assume it will?

Comment: Do you have a proper (expensive) cable tester that can certify the cable installation to the category suite? See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499) for the required tests. This is _not_ a DIY project, it requires an experienced professional.

Comment: I am a professional. I have the Fluke CIQ-100 (although this only tests to 1000BASE-TX, not 10GBASE-T. I primarily work with CAT6 residential installs / small (basic) commercial business that don't care about 10G speeds. This is a tad bigger of a project but the same principals. The companies IT folks said to use CAT6e for the install -- I'm beginning to think they may indeed want CAT6A which will complicate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cat.6e" isn't a thing. It's a vague term used by various vendors to advertise "something better than Cat. 6". So, you'd need to ask that vendor on how their "Cat. 6e" interoperates.

For 10GBASE-T over the full 100 m you'll need **Cat. 6*A***. And no, that won't likely work with a Cat. 6 panel.

Cat. 6A is hard to install correctly, passing certification, even for an experienced installer. Since you're asking, you might lack that experience.

Comment: I have loads of experience with CAT6 and below. CAT6a is a new animal for me but gotta start somewhere. Thanks for the clarification. Now to save 15K for the Fluke tester....

Answer (score 1):

Cat6A and Cat6 are both developed for Gigabit Ethernet. This cables  can handle 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX, 1000BASE-TX, and 10GBASE-T rate.seems to be  Cat6A and Cat6 cables are having same features, . In word cat6A word “A” stands for augmented, which makes Cat6A  behave differently in performance, size of cable

But only concern to be considered is Cat6A cable is thicker than comparied with Cat6 cable . For both cat6A &Cat6 cables can use same RJ45 . While cabling beacuse if cat6A cable is thicker than Cat6 cable for floding cable there will be no space  in patch panel if you use cat6 patch panel for Cat6A cable.

Comment: You should use the proper denomination Cat. 6**A** (capital *A*) for certified cabling - depending on vendor, Cat. 6**a** may be inferior.

Comment: Thanks for inputs edited accordingly