# RJ 45 Ethernet cable for Industrial purpose

Tags: ethernet

For an Industrial Solution, I have to use 8 Core cable more than 200 terminals to my device for maximum length of 4 to 8 meters. this for push button signal and switch indicators from micro control circuit board. I am planning to use Ethernet CAT5 shielded cable for this purpose. (shielded cable planning because it laying near heavy electrical motor and EMI/EMC noisy area) Any experts experienced this kind of solution or any body expecting any kind of issues in this approach?

Comment: Actually, Category-5 was de-registered in the last century, replaced by Category-5e. Also, no category cables, other than Category-8, are shielded. The shields on any other valid categories (currently, only 3, 5e, 6, and 6a) are used by vendors to get inferior cable that would not otherwise pass the category [test suite](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499) to pass the test suite.

Comment: Are you actually using Ethernet signaling or something else?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about networking but about cabling, making it off-topic here. You might want to try on [electronics.se].

Answer (score 1):

Use cat5e with shielding FTP / SFTP for good EMI protection.

Cables are available also in kevlar, PVC, ... jackets in combination with IP protection ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code ).