# Cat.6 RJ45 pass through connector issues

Tags: networking

I am planning to use Cat.6 RJ45 pass through connectors in an office network with around 70 LAN cables. I am worrying if the copper wire endings open in air will have any problems when humidity is high. The humidity in my region may be between 60% to 85%. Would anyone please kindly share your experience in the stability and performance on using this kind of plugs?
Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "_Cat.6 RJ45 pass through connectors_?" All cable ends need to be terminated. The punch down sockets create an airtight connection. Also, remember that splices, taps, couplers, etc., are not allowed in a cable run, and building your own patch cables is disallowed as you will never be able to pass the Category-6 test suite. The standard requires you to use factory-built patch cables.

Comment: I don't know how to attach a jpg file of the hardware I mentioned to illustrate. You may type "RJ45 pass through connectors CAT 6 crimp tool" in google search and set selection criteria to "images". Then you will see pictures of RJ45 plug with the small 8 copper wires of CAT 6 cable passing through the tip of the plug. This poking out wires will be trimmed off by a special crimp tool at the same time when it punches the 8 small blazes into the 8 small wires.

Comment: You should not be crimping plugs. The sockets for the solid-core, horizonal cable are what you punch down and get to pass the category test suite, but you will never get homemade, stranded, patch cables using the plugs to pass the category test suite, which is why the _ANSI/TIA/EIA 568 Commercial Building Telecommunications Cabling Standard_ disallows such cables and requires factory-built patch cables.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the specification from one of the manufacturer of Cat.6 RJ45 pass through connectors. It stated that the relative humidity of operation environment has to be under 60% and no water vapor condensation. The climate in my region is too humid to use this pass through connectors.

Thank you very much for Ron and Zac67 expert advice!

Answer (score 1):

> I am planning to use Cat.6 RJ45 pass through connectors

There is no such thing inside the Cat.6 specification. You should check out ISO/IEC 11801 or ANSI/TIA-568.

> in an office network with around 70 LAN cables.

You need to use solid-core plenum cable for office deployment. Those are terminated in patch panels in a wiring cabinet and in wall jacks in the offices. You cannot use connectors on those cables. The cable should be deployed by an experienced technician and needs to be certified before use.

Do not deploy stranded cable (potentially) suitable for crimping: the specs only allow a maximum of 10 m of stranded cable in any connection. The 100 m range can only be reached by using 90 m of solid-core cable and up to 5 m on each side of stranded patch cable.

Also, don't try to crimp that stranded cable yourself. You're quickly outside the specs and it's not really worth the trouble, considering the cost of ready-made patch cable.

Comment: Please see my illustration of the product in my reply to Ron. "RJ45 pass through connector plug for CAT 6" makes the RJ45 plug termination process far much easier and quicker. This product had been on the market a few years. However it is not very popular. I cannot get it from electronic shop outlets in my town. I can only get it from online shops. I wonder the reason why. The cons of this product that I can only think of is short-circuit when there is water vapor condensation.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any illustration. I was referring to the Cat.6 *specifications*. Sadly, there are countless products on the market that *claim* to be Cat.6 but very likely aren't. Good thing when they're not too popular. Open ends cause signal reflections which are lethal to high-rate transmissions - you should worry about that, not only about corrosion.

Comment: A local shop might not offer such a product because they don't want you to return and complain about it. Online shops are less prone to that.

Comment: @ChristinaFung, there is much crap sold for cable system parts. It has been my experience that people asking questions like this one are not really qualified to do their own cabling. Simple electrical connectivity that works for analog telephone systems is not sufficient for modern networking. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499) for the minimum required tests, which require an expensive cable tester used by cabling professionals.

Comment: There are traditional unshielded RJ45 8P8C Cat. 6 plug of staggered wire alignment. Each blaze has 2 or 3 prongs for  punching both solid-core or stranded wire. It comes with load bar to ensure the length of stripped outer coating less than 1.3cm. After plugged into the PC, there will be no more movement of the plug and PC. What is your opinion on using such solid-core Cat. 6 cable as patch cable?

Comment: Solid-core isn't suitable as patch cable, it breaks easily.