# Do wiremap testers detect split pairs

Tags: cisco, networking, troubleshooting

I was watching a How-to video on Youtube on wiremap testers and the technician said that wiremap testers detect split pairs among other wiring faults. However, I came across a Networking question asking about a wiring fault that couldn't be detected by wiremap testers, and to my suprise, the answer was split pairs.
I would like to know which is correct, the technician in the video or the answer to the question?

Comment: In modern UTP cabling, the wire map is only one small part of the required test suite. A proper cable tester (several $thousand) will perform the full category test suite. The primary tests are included in [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499).

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

Most do, but not necessarily all of them - some just test for DC continuity and shorts. While the term is widely understood among professionals, there may be vendors trying to fool you. After all, there's no industry standard for "wiremap tester".

Make sure you check the technical specification before buying.

Comment: Thanks so much.